# Vertex pertubation along an edge and a triangle

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am trying to implement a *mesh generation* algorithm. Input to the algorithm is a set of constraints(imposed on output mesh) called *Piecewise Linear Complex*(PLC) which is a collection of vertices $V\subset\mathbb R^3$, edges $E=\{(a,b)|a,b \in V\}$ and triangles $T=\{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)|\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in V\}$.

In one of the stages of the algorithm I need to perturb a vertex $v$ along an edge $e$, similarly I also need to perturb a vertex along the plane of a triangle $t$. Perturbation should be the *smallest* non-zero disturbance which will preserve *Delaunay edge* property for all edges in $E$.

My assumed definition of a Delaunay edge is: An edge is Delaunay, iff there exists a circumsphere of its endpoints not containing any other vertex inside it.

So I have two problems:

**Perturbation along an edge:**

In this case, I think that I need to shift the vertex by a *small* step along both directions on the edge and test in which case Delaunay property of all edges is preserved. But how should I decide the step size?

**Perturbation along a triangle:**

Extending my basic approach to 2 dimensions, my step will be a 2D tuple now and again I don't know how to decide its value?

Since perturbation should be the *smallest* possible disturbance, it seems to me that step size will be different for different machine representations.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any other more *efficient*(requiring lesser number of operations) approach for this vertex perturbation problem?
2. If not, can we decide step size which can work reliably regardless of machine representation?

P.S.: Reference paper for this problem is [here](http://www.imr.sandia.gov/papers/imr14/si.pdf).(Section 6: Removing local degeneracies)

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. You first talk about line and a point. Then you are talking about edges. How the edges are formed? I believe the step size should be part of an algorithm should not be machine dependent. But things are not clear to me and can't answer it properly.